# How to add more than 1 class to an element in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I'm trying to programatically add a second class to a `<td>` element in C#.

The element I want to add the class to already has a class assigned to it.

If I do something like

```
myObject.CssClass = "MyClass";
```

it simply overwrites the original class.

I suppose I could do something like

```
myObject.CssClass += " MyClass";
```

but that's ugly..

*disclaimer - I hate the idea of doing anything with HTML/CSS in C#, but I've been assigned to apply a quick fix to an already diabolical code-base. I don't see any point in trying to 'polish a turd' here, so please don't shoot me down!! :-)

Comment: And why is that ugly ? a CSS class is just a string, after all.

Comment: I think you answered your own question in your post.

Comment: it's ugly because I'm doing string concatonation with spaces in C#. Ideally there'd be a CSSList property that I could add *all* the classes to, and when it's rendered it'd spill them into the `class` attribute

Comment: Ugly or not i think you'll just have to file this one under "it is what it is", and like Timores said a string is what it is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't like to deal with string concatenation you could create some helper extension methods. Maybe more code, but you can add and remove classes without seeing what goes behind. And maybe the code will look clearer where you use it.

```
myObject.AddCssClass("someclass");
myObject.RemoveCssClass("someclass");

---------

public static class WebHelper
{
    public static void AddCssClass(this WebControl control, string cssClass)
    {
        List<string> classes;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.CssClass))
        {
            classes = control.CssClass.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            if (!classes.Contains(cssClass))
                classes.Add(cssClass);
        }
        else
        {
            classes = new List<string> {cssClass};
        }
        control.CssClass = string.Join(" ", classes.ToArray());
    }

    public static void RemoveCssClass(this WebControl control, string cssClass)
    {
        List<string> classes = new List<string>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.CssClass))
        {
            classes = control.CssClass.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        }
        classes.Remove(cssClass);
        control.CssClass = string.Join(" ", classes.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael. If there was an 'above and beyond the call of duty' badge, this answer would deserve it!

Comment: Sometimes it's better to show an alternative instead of saying "it is what it is" and the code was pretty straight forward :) Hope it helps.

Comment: @MikaelSvenson How do I add multiple classes or remove multiple classes? Thanks for the method.

Comment: Been a while since I wrote this, but call the method multiple times, once per class you want to add should work. Or extend it to take multiple classes at once. Should be straight forward to make it params string[] as input and handle the logic.