# How to add an additional css class from code behind using ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, vb.net

How to add an additional css class from code behind using ASP.NET?

**CURRENT TEXTBOX**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" CssClass="MyClass" runat="Server" />
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" CssClass="MyClass Error" runat="Server" />
```

---

**Testing**

```
txt.CssClass = "Error"
```

*This replaces current css class.*

```
txt.CssClass = "MyClass Error"
```

*This works but but is greatly inefficient having to specify class.*

```
txt.Attributes.Add("class", "Error")
```

*This only works if no initial class is set.*

```
txt.Attributes("class") += " Error"
```

*This does not work for me.*

Comment: `txt.CssClass = txt.CssClass + " Error"`.

Comment: or perhaps txt.CssClass += " Error" would work

Comment: @mikey I also believe so, but am unable to test it right now.

Comment: @MelanciaUK yes same here ;) that is why I went with 'perhaps'

Comment: @MelanciaUK this works but isn't this the same as +=  ? Please post this as an answer so you can have the reward you deserve.

Comment: Try the `+=` then. If it works, @mikey should have the credit.

Comment: Somebody needs to claim their gold stars =D

Comment: Give it to Rob W, the utility methods he's linked to are more robust.  I imagine that one could become very frustrated dealing with the string concatenation and the helper methods help to prevent duplicates

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add additional CssClass like this:

```
txt.CssClass = txt.CssClass + " Error"
```

The above can also be abbraviated as:

```
txt.CssClass += " Error"
```

Answer (score 3):

I know that you were looking for a quick one-liner.  However, this previous answer may prove useful going forward:

[How to add more than 1 class to an element in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896303/how-to-add-more-than-1-class-to-an-element-in-asp-net)